# How to read from Api with different root_node

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to config an ember app using ember-data to connect and read data from one api.
My model is:

```
App.Movie = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  rating_average: DS.attr 'string'
  short_plot: DS.attr 'string'
  free: DS.attr 'boolean'
```

My api returns:

```
{
"pagination": {
    "count":xx,
    "page": x,
    "total_pages": x
},
"movies": [
    {
        "id": xxxx,
        "title": "xxx",
        "rating_average": "x",
        "short_plot": "xxxx",
        "already_seen": x,
 ....
 ....
```

When ember try lo load data it throws:

```
Assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key **pagination** but you have no mapping for it
```

Ember does not expect the "pagination" keys in the Json. How can I specify that only try to read from the key 'movies' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to customize ember-data to handle this, consider using ember-model instead. ember-data works best when you have control over your API and can ensure that it follows a set of conventions. If that is not the case you will find yourself fighting to make ember-data work with your API and it was simply not designed for this use case. ember-model was designed for this use case and while it does less for you out-of-box it will be much easier to customize. See [ember-model-introduction](http://blog.sensible.io/2013/06/26/ember-model-introduction.html) to learn more.

That said, to make things work with ember-data you'll need to extend the rest adapter and customize it's `ajax` function.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'App.Adapter'
});
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
    var promise = this._super(url, type, hash);
    return promise.then(function(json) {
      delete json.pagination;
      return json;
    });
  }
});
```

In this custom adapter we are calling the rest adapter's ajax function - see [source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L475) - which returns a promise. The promise's then() function can be used to strip the key `pagination` from the result. Of course that means the `pagination` key will be removed from every json response.